# Retrieve images with names from database to ListView

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a desktop chat app in which a user can search other users by name or email.
When I search other users their images are not in a sequential manner.

// This is code from Home Form

```
    private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Friends.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            UsersClass.SearchContacts(listAllContacts, ImgListAllContacts, TxtSearch.Text.Trim());
        }
    }
```

// This is Code from UserClass

```
    public static void SearchContacts(ListView listview, ImageList imagelist, string searchkey)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        listview.Items.Clear();
        ListViewItem[] listviewitem = null;
        dt = DataBaseAccess.Retrive("select UID,FullName,DP from TKDBUsers WHERE ( FullName+' '+UserName ) Like '%" + searchkey + "%' AND UID != '" + LogInUser.UID + "'");
        if (dt != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                listviewitem = new ListViewItem[(dt.Rows.Count)];
                int LC = 0;        //List contacts
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Image img = DataBaseAccess.Base64ToImage(Convert.ToString(item["DP"]));
                    imagelist.Images.Add(img);
                    listviewitem[LC] = new ListViewItem(new string[] { Convert.ToString(item["UID"]) + " - " + Convert.ToString(item["FullName"]) }, LC);
                    LC++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (listviewitem != null)
        {
            listview.Items.AddRange(listviewitem);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM0LR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LX2uA.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "not in a sequential manner"? If you want them in a certain order (by name or whatever else), you can use an `order by` clause in your query.

Comment: yes that's what I mean Order by " Name "

Comment: Did you try adding "Order by Name" in select query?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't not store data in any particular order or retrieve data in any particular order.  The database is multi-threaded and performing same query can get different results every time.  You must use an Order By in a query to make sure results come out in same order every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to clear your imagelist ?

Comment: I clear the imagelist but still image of one user is shown in other user place.

Comment: @MuhammadMansoorIshaq I suggest you take a look at my answer also. Add "Order by".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the select query to (add "ORDER BY UserName"):

```
dt = DataBaseAccess.Retrive("
    SELECT UID, FullName, DP 
    FROM TKDBUsers 
    WHERE (FullName+' '+UserName ) LIKE '%" + searchkey + "%' 
    AND UID != '" + LogInUser.UID + "' 
    ORDER BY UserName");
```